# how to convert json into string without line break and the other format

Tags: java, android, json

I'm setting up a new server and android, and want to send base64(image) from android to server. I use JSON for data format between android and server, so I have to put my base64 into that JSON, but the server cannot decode my base64 because there are a symbol like "\n,+," and many more. I also try using Notepad for replace "\n" but still the server wont decode it..

note:
if I use Postman the server work properly

```
JSONArray data = new JSONArray();

for (int i = 0; i < listImage.size(); i++) {
    //listImage.get(i).setBase64(map.get(listImage.get(i).getId()));
    jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("id",listImage.get(i).getId());
    jsonObject.put("base64",map.get(listImage.get(i).getId()));
    data.put(jsonObject);
}

jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("image",data);
```

Comment: show how you convert image to base64. Also show which JSON you get before sending it to the server

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to convert jason object to a String

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject has toString() method that return json object data into String format. You can also look at UTF encoding to encode special character, to make http request without conflicting of special character in URL.

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("image",data);
jsonObject.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer guys...I have found my own solution, I need to replace "\n" and "\" with "" from base64 in server side